# Xcode 9.3. How to hide view statusbar in xib?

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, xcode9.3

In Xcode < 9.3 we can hide status bar in view in xib by setting top bar simulated metrics to `None`.

But now in 9.3, when setting this to `None`, the status bar didn't hide.

Any ideas how to hide it?

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to set simulated metrics size to "Freeform". Next, you need to change the size of your view to some custom value. After that Xcode will hide the status bar.

Comment: Thank you. It is dumb you have to do it this way, but this did work for me

Comment: This works in removing the status bar but not the iPhone x swipe up to go home bottom bar. Any suggestions for that? :(

Comment: This does not change the Safe Area though. So for auto-layout the status bar is still there.

Answer (score -4):

On your info.plist add the following two property for statusBar Hidden

**View controller-based status bar appearance (Boolean: NO)**

**Status bar is initially hidden (Boolean: YES)**

By Source

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

**or**

[image]

Comment: This will hide status bar for all the screens.